Для чего указывают рандомные классы?
На многих сайтах я замечал такую штуку, что некоторые указывают класс тега рандомными буквами. Скажем, для нас привычный вид это «header”, а они указывают «Gdbdu7hd”, для чего это делается? И как такое же использовать на моем сайте? Что за библиотека?


Из вопроса не понятно, о чем вы, однако предположу, что один из вариантов, это библиотека styledcomponents. Только она совсем не о рандомности, а о динамической стилизации элементов(state/props)

Приведите конкретный пример разметки прямо в вопросе

Ща приложу скриншот

Добавил картинку

обфускация здесь применима?

обфускация тут вообще ни к чему

А автогенерация?

Вопрос прочитай

Все таки, зачем вам такое использовать на вашем сайте, если вы не знаете, зачем это делается? Может там у разраба "фетиш" такой и ему нравятся такие имена классов...

Зачем тебе использовать если ты даже не знаешь для чего это применяется и когда?

Чтобы ты спросил

В React этим занимается библиотека styled-components, в ней есть весь необходимый готовый функционал и примеры использования.
В обычном webpack проекте такого можно добиться с помощью встроенной в css-loader опции module и гибко настроить генерацию уникального имени css правила.
Пример загрузчика в конфиге:
{
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        modules: {
            // In Dev only
            //localIdentName:'[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
            
            // Production
            localIdentName:'[hash:base64:10]',
        },
    },
},


Пример использования
.css файл:
:global body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.text {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.js файл:
import styles from "./style.css";

const element = document.querySelector(".element");

element.innerHTML = `<div class="${styles.page}">
    <p class="${styles.text}">CSS Modules Webpack</p>
</div>`;

Результат исходного кода:
<div class="element">
    <div class="_dXGhaRn5sCToGGGDCh">
        <p class="CHJ8S9DbrdfTxcs_BEte">CSS Modules Webpack</p>
    </div>
</div>


Так а для чего это делают?

@user592585, Защита от скрапинга (либо усложнение, защитой трудно назвать), оптимизация (уменьшение кода, минимизация), в рантайме отрезает лишние стили, предотвращение конфликтов стилей. Получаются более чистые компоненты, более закрытые. Но всё тоже самое можно сделать и на обычном, традиционном решении.

Понял, спасибо))
